# Get text from all instances of XML element using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to parse XML files where I can't predict the structure. I need to fill a string array with the inner text from every instance of the below tag no matter where they occur in the tree.

```
<SpecialCode>ABCD1234</SpecialCode>
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this using c#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grab All XML Elements of a Specific Type: Even nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424845/grab-all-xml-elements-of-a-specific-type-even-nested-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

If your XML is a string:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<SpecialCode>ABCD1234</SpecialCode>");
string[] specialCodes = doc.Descendants("SpecialCode").Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();
```

If your XML is a file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("specialCodes.xml");
string[] specialCodes = doc.Descendants("SpecialCode").Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();
```

**Explanation**

`XDocument` is a handy class that allows for easy XML parsing. You'll need to add a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly to your project in order to use it.

- The `Descendents` method will get *all* children of the XML document, which takes care of your unknown XML structure.
- The `Select` method is a LINQ method and allows us to select a property from each node--in this case, `Value`.
- `ToArray` converts the IEnumerable result from `Select()` to your desired result.

Comment: Is it also possible to scrape all parameters called "id"? ie. <SpecialCode id=XYZ>ABCD1234</SpecialCode>

Comment: Got it: string[] specialCodes = doc.Descendants("SpecialCodes").Select(n => n.FirstAttribute.Value).ToArray();

Comment: You will loose the hierarchy with this approach.  I usually use a recursive algorithm so I keep the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(FILENAME);

// IN CASE OF STRING, USE FOLLOWING
//doc.LoadXml(XAML_STRING);

XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//SpecialCode");
```

// prefic will fetch all the `SpecialCode` tags from xml.